# Which test or method can I use to assess trend in dependent proportions over time?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, trend, generalized-estimating-equations

Let's assume there are 4 time points, t0 (baseline) ... t3

At each time point I assess a % of successes of some outcome: p0, p1...p3. The denominators vary over time, so the counts itself do not suffice: n1/N1, n2/N2... n3/N3.

The data are repeated observations - the patients are assessed, so within-subject covariances have to be accounted for.

I need to say, whether there is a monotonous trend in them, non-increasing or non-decreasing. Ideally I'd also interested in quadratic or other trends.

I was proposed:

1. the Cochran-Armitage test for trend in proportions. But this doesn't assume they are dependent, as far as I know.
2. GEE or mixed-effect logistic regression.

- I could use the time as a continuous variable. The times are equal for all subjects, so it should work. This would tell me if there is a trend over time, either linear or other (it the variable is squared or cubed)
- I could use the time as it is - ordered categorical variable and use a set of contrasts for trends: linear, quadratic, cubed.

Do you have any other recommendation for that? Or do you find any issues with the proposed solutions?

Comment: It's best to state the problem in terms of raw data.  I assume you have correlated binary sequences.  It is necessary to account for within-subject correlations.  The clearest way to do this is to use a Markov transition model, but with some luck, random effects may work if the time span isn't long.  See [here](https://fharrell.com/post/re).

Comment: I don't have the data yet, it's being planned. Yes, as I mentioned, within-subject covariances will have to be accounted for, that's why I proposed a mixed model or GEE estimation. My client wants the marginal model and not subject-conditional one, so I will stick probably with GEE. I was just wondering, if using the logistic regression will make sense and what's your advice on the trend? To keep the time continuous and assess T, T^2, T^3... or keep it categorical ordered and test contrast: linear, quadratic? I cannot predict the form, it may be any, I'm interested only in the direction. GAM?

Comment: GEE is an approximately method that is not robust to dropouts, but it is flexible.  As I mentioned in the blog article, marginal models often answer the question of interest.  Models that really model the correlation pattern (e.g. Markov models) work better.  It's good to try to keep time continuous in both the correlation structure and in the mean model.  Depending on how many distinct times there are a cubic spline function for time works very well for the mean (outcome) model.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have never used Markov models, I will learn about. For the dropouts, I think I will use weighted GEE with inverse probability, however I don't expect a large one. I have only four time points, so maybe I went too far - what I can check is just whether the trend goes up or down (or stays stable) :-) Thank you very much for your extensive answer and your time!

Comment: Note that inverse probability weights are so inefficient, as Phil Lavori has shown, that the effect of every dropout effectively takes down up to 7 patients who don't drop out.  You have to use multiple imputation to help GEE along.  Best to use a full likelihood approach that doesn't require multiple imputation.

Comment: That's true, but the random effects require approximate normality, which I cannot expect a priori (or I need to use robust SE then). I also know, that the GLMM are sensitive to the specification of the model (GEE is quite robust). I will start from unstructured covariance (or, equivalently in GLMM - random intercepts and slopes), but I cannot predict if it will converge, so maybe simpler structures will be necessary. I wouldn't like t play with the G and R matrix in mixed models, rather stick only with the R covariance using the GEE, making it simpler. Thank you for the advice on the MI!